# PostgreSQL setting pg_hba.config file

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, passwords, set

I am pretty new to databases and also using the command prompt.  I've been trying to create a database but first I believe I need to set the pg_hba.config file.  When I open SQL shell it says"

Server [localhost]:
ENTER
Database[postgres]:
ENTER
Port [5432]:
ENTER
Username [postgres]:
ENTER
Password for user postgres:

And then it won't let me type anything there, so I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on Windows, and you're starting `psql`.

When you type the password it's receiving it, but it's just not showing the characters as a security measure. It's like replacing the characters with bullets.

Just type the password and press enter.